# How to segment ts format file

Tags: gstreamer, http-live-streaming

I'm working on some HLS app with latest version(1.2.0) of GStreamer on Ubuntu 13.10 
and be troubled by hlssink plugin.

While getting segments from a ts file, the cmd as follow :

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test.ts ! tsdemux name=demuxer ! multiqueue name=mq ! 'video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream,alignment=nal' ! mpegtsmux name=mux ! hlssink  mq. ! 'audio/mpeg,mpegversion=2,stream-format=adts' ! mux.
```

I found it dumps the segments ts files with wrong type, and no player can play back those files.
But when I demux from mp4 format, it works :

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demuxer demuxer. ! multiqueue name=mq ! h264parse ! mpegtsmux name=mux ! hlssink demuxer. ! mq.  mq. ! aacparse ! mux.
```

really troubled a lot by this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is it a requirement to use GStreamer? FFmpeg or libav can do the demux and segmentation.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: try with ffmpeg and it should be good to go. Also, as you have the mp4, you can check any mp4 parser and see if something is wrong with that file which is causing that issue.